# What does the "glGenSyncTokenCHROMIUM" error mean?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm debugging a WebGL application, and the following error message pops up in my console, right after a call to [`compileShader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/compileShader) and [`getShaderInfoLog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getShaderInfoLog):

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenSyncTokenCHROMIUM: fence sync must be flushed before generating sync token
```

I've searched *teh interwebs* for `glGenSyncTokenCHROMIUM`, with no avail.

(This error seems to be hardware-specific, as I can only reproduce it on a [GT-I9505](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9505_galaxy_s4-5371.php) when running Chrome)

What does this error mean, and/or how can I get more detailed information of what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be indeed device/GPU/driver problem. There's [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615651) in Chromium bug tracker (by the way, you can provide your case to it).

There're several ways to get information and help on WebGL bugs. Besides StackOverflow, there is [WebGL google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/webgl-dev-list) (browser developers also active in it). Bugtrackers may be helpful (you always can and should report bugs to developers). And, if you feel like it, Chrome and Firefox have excellent code search engines ([ff](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/), [cr](https://cs.chromium.org)), more than once I've found answers to my questions there.

Comment: As it turns out, conditionally modifying a component of a varying vector in the vertex shader will trigger a shader compilation error in some GPUs, and Chrome will throw that error. That bug report and the tips are useful!!